# Using UTM instead of latlong when using an embedded map in c# app

Tags: c#, uwp, esri, utm, arcgis-runtime

So I have a mobile app that collects data and one of the components is a map that shows your location in the world.

This app is created using c# UWP and I am using ESRI ArcGISRuntime for the spatial component.

I have the map created and when I move around I am able to show my location as latitude and longitude. I am able to get my location in real time in both decimal degrees and degrees minute seconds, as well as the altitude using Coordinate.Point.Position.

I would like to have the option of showing my location in UTM coordinates but I have not found a simple way like I can with with lat long.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [CoordinateFormatter](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/uwp/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.CoordinateFormatter.html). It has a [ToUtm()](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/uwp/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.CoordinateFormatter.ToUtm.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_CoordinateFormatter_ToUtm_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MapPoint_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_UtmConversionMode_System_Boolean_) method that takes a MapPoint (which can be in any spatial reference) and some info about how to convert it to a UTM string.

Hope that helps

Comment: So I am not the best when it comes to coding using arcGISRuntime.  I use Coordinate.Point.Position to get the latitude and longitude (ex. _currentLatitude = in_position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;)  If I want to get the UTM would I go _currentNorthing = CoordinateFormatter.ToUtm(in_position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, UtmConversionMode.NorthSouthIndicators, true);